# Can I remove static assets from a theme?

Tags: hugo

I’m using a hugo theme (sam) that installs some static assets (`themes/sam/static/`), some pictures and an unused css file. Is it possible not to install them? I know I can `touch` them in `static/` and install zero-byte versions, but is it possible not to install them in the first place?

Comment: Just remove the static assets from `themes/sam/static/`

Comment: That’s true, and definitely the simplest. I’m just curious whether there’s a way to specify it from config though, to save having to do it manually with every fresh checkout.

Comment: What do you mean by "to save having to do it manually with every fresh checkout"? Are you updating the template using `git pull`? If that so, just don't do it that way